# Correct types to pass props down to children in react typescript. Error ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have my code working in Javascript, but cannot make it work in typescript. The question might seem long and complex, but its not. I just wanted to post the working JS code to have a solid starting point for the question.

I pass my project list with dummy data from the dashboard to a project list component like this:

Dashboard component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ProjectList from '../projects/ProjectList'
import Notifications from './Notifications'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    
    // console.log(this.props);
    const { projects } = this.props; //TYPE PROBLEM 1 EXPLAINED BELOW
    
    return (
      <div className="dashboard container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s12 m6">
            <ProjectList projects={projects} /> //TYPE PROBLEM 2 EXPLAINED BELOW "ts(2322)"
          </div>
          <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
            <Notifications />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    projects: state.project.projects
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard)
```

My projectList component:

```
import React from 'react'
import ProjectSummary from './ProjectSummary'

const ProjectList = ({projects}) => { //TYPE PROBLEM 3 EXPLAINED BELOW
  return (
    <div className="project-list section">
      { projects && projects.map(project => {
        return (
          <ProjectSummary project={project} key={project.id} />
        )
      })}  
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProjectList
```

And my project reducer:

```
const initState = {
  projects: [
    {id: '1', title: 'help me find peach', content: 'blah blah blah'},
    {id: '2', title: 'collect all the stars', content: 'blah blah blah'},
    {id: '3', title: 'egg hunt with yoshi', content: 'blah blah blah'}
  ]
}

const projectReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  return state;
};

export default projectReducer;
```

//TYPE PROBLEM 1:
Tried geneting my own types, but did not make any work along the project data pass chain. Destructuring also seem to be a problem. I tried to fit the data type provided by the props:

```
export interface IProject {
  id: string,
  title: string,
  content: string
}

export interface IProjectState {
  readonly projects: IProject[]
}
```

//TYPE PROBLEM 2:
I also tried `React.ReactNode` and `React.FC<IProjec>[]` but I keep getting an error:

```
Type '{ projects: IProject[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProject[]'.
  Property 'projects' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IProject[]'.ts(2322)
```

//TYPE PROBLEM 3:
Here I need to loop (map) through my project, so I would need my type also to fit with that.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment I resolved it like this:

```
interface Props {
  projects: IProject[];
}

class Dashboard extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    const { ...props } = this.props;
    //console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="dashboard container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col s12 m6">
            <ProjectList projects={props.projects}/>
            </div>
          <div className="col s12 m5 offset-m1">
            <Notifications />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}



const mapStateToProps = (state: IAppState) => {
  return {
    projects: state.project.projects
  }
    
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dashboard);
```

For a reason I do not fully underestand, it seems you cannot work directly with the prop type, in my case the project type:

```
interface IProject {
  id: string,
  title: string,
  content: string
}
```

And had to wrap it in another type/interface:

```
interface Props {
  projects: IProject[];
}
```

Which needs to be passed to the component type the dashboard extends from like this: `class Dashboard extends Component<Props>`